# Showing the solution to a differential equation is periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an initial value problem for which I have to show that the the function is periodic. The definition and lemmas I can use is:

1. We say a function $f$ is periodic if $f(t) = f(t + T)$ for some period $T$
2. Given $f$ which is continuous and periodic with period $T$. Then for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $\int_a^{a+T} f(t) dt = \int_0^T f(t) dt$

The given differential equation is $y' + cy = cos(t)$ with inital condition $y(0) = b$. Im asked to find its solution and show that $y(t)$ is periodic if and only if $b = \frac{c}{c^2 + 1}$. I got $y(t) = \frac{sin (t) + c cos (t)}{c^2 + 1} + \frac{d}{e^{ct}}$ where $d$ is an arbitrary constant. Solving at $y(0) = b$ I get $b = \frac{c}{c^2 + 1} + d$. How do I go about showing its periodic? Im almost there but i dont quite know what to do next.

Comment: Do you know that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic, and $e^{ct}$ is not?

Comment: @DuduBob yes but the only thing that is causing an issue is the constant $d$. If constant $d$ was equal to 0 then we get that $b = \frac{c}{c^2+1}$. But I cant just assume $d = 0$ without justifying it

Comment: Right. So if $d = 0$, then $b = \frac{c}{c^2+1}$ and the solution is periodic, which is exactly what you want. If $d \neq 0$, then $b \neq \frac{c}{c^2+1}$ and the solution is not periodic, which is the other direction.

Comment: So I guess what is confusing you is this: the problem asks you to show that the solution is periodic **if and only if** $b = \frac{c}{c^2+1}$, not that the solution is periodic in all situations.

Comment: yes thats exactly what confused me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proof of this fact only requires that you recognize that $\sin(t)=\sin(t+T)$ and $\cos(t)=\cos(t+T)$, i.e. they're periodic.

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is like DuduBob is saying, if $d=0$ then $b=\cfrac{c}{c^2+1}$ and so $y(t)=e^{-ct}(b-b)+\cfrac{1}{c^2+1}(\sin(t)+c\cos(t))=\cfrac{1}{c^2+1}(\sin(t)+c\cos(t))$. The solution is periodic since $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are periodic on their own. The sum of periodic functions is again periodic.

Edit: As @Ian mentions, this is only true when the periods are commensurable, that is the ratio is a rational number. But in this case, $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ share the same period $T$, so the ratio is in fact $1$.

The $\Rightarrow$ direction is obtained by subtracting $y(t+T)-y(t):$

$y(t+T)-y(t)=(e^{-c(t+T)}-e^{-ct})d=0$. It equals $0$ since by assumption, $y(t)=y(t+T)$. Since $e^{-c(t+T)}-e^{-ct}\neq0$ (it is an exponential), then it follows that $d=0$

Comment: Minor thing: the sum of periodic functions *with commensurate periods*, i.e. with periods which are a rational multiple of one another, is periodic. In this case the periods being commensurate is trivial since they're just the same number.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Vegeta the Prince of Saiyans i dont understand how did you conclude this line $y(t) = e^{-ct}(b-b) + \frac{1}{c^2+1} (\sin (t) + c \cos(t))$?

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ It's the same as what you had, after applying the initial condition. Just written a bit differently. You can just effectively ignore the term with $b-b$, as that is zero since $d=0$.